# cp: cannot stat 'Pipfile': No such file or directory in Docker build

Tags: docker

I have a project directory setup like this:

docker and Backend are siblings

I go into my docker folder and type `docker build ./`

Theoretically, based on the relevant part of my Dockerfile, I should go to the parent directory and into Backend

```
ARG PROJECT_DIR=../Backend
WORKDIR $PROJECT_DIR
RUN cp Pipfile Pipfile.lock
```

However I get the error:

```
cp: cannot stat 'Pipfile': No such file or directory
```

I have also tried COPY and it does not work either.

Why can't I copy my Pipfile to Pipfile.lock? It exists in the Backend directory.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Copy a file from your computer to the docker image during the build? The WORKDIR will set the workdir inside your docker image that you are building, not from your computer. Try `RUN pwd` and see the output, you will understand.

Comment: I am trying to access my files in ../Backend/ and copy the Pipfile to Pipfile.lock - is that not how I would do that?

Answer (score 4):

You need to understand that two things:

1. A docker build actually instantiate a container using the base image (`FROM`) do the changes specified on your `Dockerfile` and create a new image from the final state of this container.
2. A docker container have a isolated filesystem. You cannot access external files from it unless you configure a volume (and volumes are not available on Dockerfile/docker build process

So, to put files inside your docker image, you use the COPY command. The first argument is the original file path, from the directory of your Dockerfile. Files outside is inaccessible for security reasons.

If you need to access a file outside the Dockerfile directory, you probably placed it in the wrong place.

Answer (score 0):

Docker is a client (`docker`) <> server (`dockerd`, running as a daemon) application. When you type `docker build...` the client compresses the context (specified in your example as `./`) and sends that to the server (which in most cases is running on the same machine, but that's really irrelevant here). That means anything that's *not* in the context is unavailable to the build process (which is done by the server).

So now you can see why things in a 'sibling' directory are not available, they aren't part of the context, and aren't sent to the daemon for the build.

Reference more info here: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/#extended-description